# Is it possible to break a table into multiple layout columns?

Tags: html, css, html-table, accessibility, css-grid

Is it possible to arrange label/value pairs into a column layout, but breaking into multiple columns when the content exceeds a given number of rows?

For example, I have a list of 9 label/value pairs. I want the labels and values to be vertically aligned. For accessibility purposes, the content should read top to bottom (label1 to label9) but the visual layout should break after 6 rows, like this:

```
[labelOne   ][   valueOne][labelSeven ][ valueSeven]
[labelTwo   ][   valueTwo][labelEight ][ valueEight]
[labelThree ][ valueThree][labelNine  ][  valueNine]
[labelFour  ][  valueFour]
[labelFive  ][  valueFive]
[labelSix   ][   valueSix]
```

The markup should be semantically ordered for accessibility purposes:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">labelOne</th>
      <td>valueOne</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- etc -->
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">labelNine</th>
      <td>valueNine</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can split a table using CSS columns!
https://codepen.io/joemaffei/pen/abNKrJJ

```css
.columns {
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8.25em;
}

table {
  background: orange;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='columns'>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">labelOne</th>
        <td>valueOne</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">labelTwo</th>
        <td>valueTwo</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">labelThree</th>
        <td>valueThree</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">labelFour</th>
        <td>valueFour</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">labelFive</th>
        <td>valueFive</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">labelSix</th>
        <td>valueSix</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">labelSeven</th>
        <td>valueSeven</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">labelEight</th>
        <td>valueEight</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">labelNine</th>
        <td>valueNine</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: don't forget **you need column headers for a table to be semantically correct.** Add column headers to your example and see if it still works as expected. Also you state you want the labels and values to be vertically aligned, is that the reasoning behind a table (for the alignment)? If so you have accidentally travelled back in time 20 years to when tables were used for layouts! hehe. Perhaps an (ordered?) list and spans would be more appropriate, just something to consider.

Comment: The vertical alignment here is more of a bonus. I thought label/value pairs could be semantically correct as tabular data using row headers. Could you give an example of a more semantically correct way of presenting a list of label/value pairs? I've tried description lists but NVDA doesn't read them correctly.